# How to redirect python warnings to a custom stream?

Tags: python, warnings, io

Let's say I have a file-like object like StreamIO and want the python's warning module write all warning messages to it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try reassigning [warnings.showwarning](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) i.e.

```
#!/sw/bin/python2.5

import warnings, sys

def customwarn(message, category, filename, lineno, file=None, line=None):
    sys.stdout.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno))

warnings.showwarning = customwarn
warnings.warn("test warning")
```

will redirect all warnings to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work, although it's untested code and the interface looks like there is a cleaner way which eludes me at present:

```
import warnings

# defaults to the 'myStringIO' file
def my_warning_wrapper(message, category, filename, lineno, file=myStringIO, line=None):
    warnings.show_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, file, line)    

warnings._show_warning = my_warning_wrapper
```

A look inside Lib\warnings.py should help put you on the right track if that isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import StringIO

sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Comment: Just a note - this is a different implementation from io.StringIO
StringIO.StringIO does not have methods such as fileno() defined, while io.StringIO has fileno() defined but not implemented.