# How to ignore deprecation warnings in Python

Tags: python, warnings, deprecated

I keep getting this :

```
DeprecationWarning: integer argument expected, got float
```

How do I make this message go away? Is there a way to avoid warnings in Python?

Comment: When nothing else works: `$ pip install shutup`. Then at the top of the code `import shutup;shutup.please()`. This will disable all warnings.

Comment: 341k views as of 2023-11-18 shows how bad this is. Why is it not a reported bug that it is so hard to switch these warning messages off once they were noticed?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

From documentation of the [`warnings` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning
```

If you're on Windows: pass `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning` as an argument to Python. Better though to resolve the issue, by casting to [int](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#int).

(Note that in Python 3.2, deprecation warnings are ignored by default.)

Comment: I wish I could make this work...  I get a `/usr/bin/env: python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning: No such file or directory` error.  It works if I run python with the `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning` option on the command-line, but /usr/bin/env doesn't deal with it.

Comment: Seems to be a windows-only solution.

Comment: You can set the env variable PYTHONWARNINGS this worked for me `export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::DeprecationWarning:simplejson"` to disable django json deprication warnings from sorl

Comment: @yvess, if this were an answer, I'd have voted for it.  Seems a clean way to ignore specific warnings systemwide.  I put it in my ~/.profile. Works great.

Comment: Hi can we some how turn this Deprecation Warning message to an message of type information. What I would like is just to display the message on the console not to be categorized as any type of warning.

Comment: The chronology here is: for Python 2.6 `DeprecationWarning`s were on by default, from Python 2.7 to Python 3.2 `DeprecationWarning`s were off by default and for Python 3.7 they are back on by default! https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0565/

Comment: This won't work on Linux because you cannot pass multiple command line arguments to shebangs. `#!/usr/bin/python -Wignore::DeprecationWarning` should work, but it's preferable to use the `warnings` module.

Comment: Using `/usr/bin/env` in the shebang just requires a `-S`, like so:
`#!/usr/bin/env -S python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning`

Answer (score 321):

You should just fix your code but just in case,

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Worked for me using iPython

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all, still seeing deprecationwarnings.

Comment: @user1244215 I could be wrong but I think it matters where in your code you run `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)`.  I think you have to run this after you import the library that's spitting out the warnings, although I could be mistaken.

Comment: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)

Comment: @CodingYourLife category is needed so you will still see other types of warnings like RuntimeWarning etc.

Comment: @user1244215 Sometimes `FutureWarnings` are given in order to deprecate things...

Comment: In my case, the code that was causing the warning was `from xgboost import XGBClassifier`. I had to put `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)` immediately before that import for it to work.

Comment: Works great to shut up the `DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead` warning when running unoconv (e. g. to convert a LibreOffice document to PDF). Just `sudo vi /usr/bin/unoconv` and insert those two lines. Tested on Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: This works! But the key is, this code has to be in the correct place. 

Moreover, the `filterwarnings` accepts a module name. I suppose one can specify the module the warning is coming from, but I haven't tested it though.

More docs here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings

Comment: Not working for me, still see LangChainDeprecationWarning

Answer (score 242):

I had these:

```
/home/eddyp/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-8.2.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/persisted/sob.py:12:
DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead import os, md5, sys

/home/eddyp/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Twisted-8.2.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/python/filepath.py:12:
DeprecationWarning: the sha module is deprecated; use the hashlib module instead import sha
```

Fixed it with:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
    import md5, sha

yourcode()
```

Now you still get all the other `DeprecationWarning`s, but not the ones caused by:

```
import md5, sha
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!!  (Took me a moment to realize I could also wrap non-import bits of code in this, since some packages were also generating DeprecationWarnings when used after import.)  Very nice way to only silence specific DeprecationWarnings that I've already looked at and decided I want to ignore.

Comment: Works on WIndows and Linux, plus is completely independent of any parameters given to the executable. So works all the time. Additionally it only disables deprecation warnings for explicit libraries, so when the next ones get deprecated you still get informed to update your source code.

Answer (score 65):

**None of these answers worked for me so I will post my way to solve this. I use the following `at the beginning of my main.py` script and it works fine.**

---

Use the following as it is (copy-paste it):

```
def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn
```

or 1-liner, thanks Philippe Remy 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python#comment133475540_50519680)

```
import warnings ; warnings.warn = lambda *args,**kwargs: None
```

Example:

```
def warn(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
import warnings
warnings.warn = warn


import "blabla"
import "blabla"

# more code here...
# more code here...
```

---

Comment: That worked when all other solutions didn't. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me too. Glad that I could help.

Comment: Doesn't work in 3.7.3 for AstroPy deprecation warnings. :(

Comment: I've wrapped this solution in a lib: $ pip install shutup. Then at the top of the code import shutup;shutup.please(). This will disable all warnings.

Comment: Work for the whole application ! Thank you so much

Comment: Same.  None of the other solutions worked.  This is the only thing that worked.

Comment: For those who want a one liner for this answer: `warnings.warn = lambda *args, **kwargs: None`

Comment: I work for me; though I have to put your code block on top of other import command

Answer (score 32):

I found the cleanest way to do this (especially on windows) is by adding the following to C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\sitecustomize.py:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Note that I had to create this file.  Of course, change the path to python if yours is different.

Answer (score 19):

##### Docker Solution

- Disable ALL warnings before running the python application

  - You can disable your dockerized tests as well

```
ENV PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore::DeprecationWarning"
```

Answer (score 8):

When you want to ignore warnings only in functions you can do the following.

```
import warnings
from functools import wraps


def ignore_warnings(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            response = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return inner

@ignore_warnings
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    ...
    write your code here without warnings
    ...

@ignore_warnings
def foo2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    ...
    write your code here without warnings
    ...
```

Just add the @ignore_warnings decorator on the function you want to ignore all warnings

Answer (score 8):

If you are using logging (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to format or redirect your ERROR, NOTICE, and DEBUG messages, you can redirect the WARNINGS from the warning system to the logging system:

```
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```

It will capture the warnings with the tag "py.warnings". Also if you want to throw away those warnings without logging, you can then, set the logging level to ERROR by using:

```
logging.getLogger("py.warnings").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

It will cause all those warnings to be ignored without showing up in your terminal or anywhere else.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings and [captureWarnings set to True doesn't capture warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531786/capturewarnings-set-to-true-doesnt-capture-warnings)

In my case, I was formatting all the exceptions with the logging system, but warnings (e.g. scikit-learn) were not affected.

Comment: "logging.captureWarnings(True)" is what did it for me. This was the only way I could get boto3 to stop spitting out a million warnings that "datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp() is deprecated".

Answer (score 7):

> Python 3

Just write below lines that are easy to remember before writing your code:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass the correct arguments? :P

On the more serious note, you can pass the argument -Wi::DeprecationWarning on the command line to the interpreter to ignore the deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the argument to int. It's as simple as

```
int(argument)
```

Answer (score 3):

For python 3, just write below codes to ignore all warnings.

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code if you're Using Python3:

```
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
```

or try this...

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

or try this...

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous solutions, if you continue to receive warnings in certain parallel applications (such as those that use `multiprocessing`, it is possible that the warning filters need to be passed to child processes as well. You can do that with something like this:

```
import sys, os

if not sys.warnoptions:
    import warnings
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    
    os.environ["PYTHONWARNINGS"] = "ignore"
```

Adding the `os.environ` line will cause subprocesses to also ignore warnings.

Answer (score -1):

If you know what you are doing, another way is simply **find the file that warns you(the path of the file is shown in warning info), comment the lines that generate the warnings.**

Comment: What if the warning comes from a third-party library?

Comment: Generally, the lines that generate the warning are required for the program to function.  Certainly a sub-optimal suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

A bit rough, but it worked for me after the above methods did not.

> ./myscrypt.py 2>/dev/null

Answer (score -3):

Not to beat you up about it but you are being warned that what you are doing will likely stop working when you next upgrade python. Convert to int and be done with it.

BTW. You can also write your own warnings handler. Just assign a function that does nothing.
[How to redirect python warnings to a custom stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858916/how-to-redirect-python-warnings-to-a-custom-stream)

Comment: That advice only works if it is indeed his own code and not from some 3rd party package.

Answer (score -10):

Comment out the **warning lines** in the below file:

```
lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py
```