# Unittest command line utilities in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a python project with the following structure

```
test/ # unit tests to be run with nosetest
bin/  # utilities written in python to be installed
packagename/ # code for the package
```

For instance, `bin/python_command` might contain:

```
@cmdline.command(usage='subcommand1 description')
def cmd_mysubcommand1(opts, args):
    '''Code for python_command mysubcommand1'''                                                                                                   



if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmdline.main('Description of python_command')
```

Where cmdline is simply a library to help with the boilerplate code of parsing arguments and subcommand.

The question is, what's considered the best practice to unittest all the subcommands of `bin/python_command` (`cmd_mysubcommand1` in particular) by including a test in the `test` directory? (i.e. they should be integrated in my current unittest suite).

Ideally, I would like to provide the textual command line of each command instead of specifically testing the final subcommand functions (to check that parsing of subcommands is working properly).

I have just read about [scripttest](http://pythonpaste.org/scripttest/) but I don't know if it integrates well with the unittest python library and whether it supports mocking some of the objects used in the subcommands (which is a must for me).

Comment: You want to unittest functions or you want to test commands (shell)? If you want to test functions, you test it like regular python things with mocking and so, I do not know why this time should be different. If you want to test a script (and it's command) it is more like integration test rather then unit test.

Comment: For one, it's different because the modules don't end with py and are not importable in a normal way (I guess there must be a way around this) but ideally I would like to test the commands with mocking.

Comment: So why you just split this code to two modules? First for python-importable module and second (the proper script with the proper name) which just imports the first and run the commands. If you look at any pip installable program with a command line interface you look that is a common practice that in virtualenv in bin there is a script which just import a function from lib/site-packages from python module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I just ended up implementing a normal unittest using softlinks to the files not ending in .py as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension)