# python-sphinx documenting scripts with no py extension

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Apologies - this is a complete n00b question:

I have a couple of python scripts with no .py extension.

How do I convince Sphinx that it should document that script? Example error:

/home/XXX/YYYYY/development/dst/build/index.rst:25: (WARNING/2) autodoc can't import/find module 'site_scons.random', it reported error: "No module named random", please check your spelling and sys.path

Answer (score 2):

In order for your script to be a module, it needs to include the `.py` suffix. From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/modules.html):

> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements. The file name is the module name with the suffix `.py` appended.

Without giving it the suffix, Sphinx won't be able to import it to generate documentation using `automodule`.

Comment: Cheers So sphinx is a module-documentation package. Surprised, as there must be a lot of scripts out there which need documenting. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: You can use it to write your own documentation. You just can't use `automodule` with something that isn't a module.

Comment: The documentation at http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html says "If you document scripts (as opposed to library modules), make sure their main routine is protected by a if __name__ == '__main__' condition."  This gives me hope that there is a way to document scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your script to end with a `.py` file extension you can also try the following.

You can write your original script into a `.py` file and create another executable (bash script) file that just executes your `.py` file. That way, you can document the script (the `.py`) file using sphinx and still execute it through the other executable file.

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007193/8280541) by @dirn, a module requires a `.py` extension to be considered as such.

An alternate solution that I think is cleaner, though it requires more work:

- Create a directory named `links` on your Sphinx root folder (that is, it will be a sibling to `source` and `build`)
- On that directory, create relative links to your scripts, adding `.py` to their names
- Add this new directory to the Python PATH on `conf.py`, under `Path setup`:  `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../links'))`
- Now, you can use something like `.. automodule:: my_command` to have your script read as a module and documented.

A sample project would look like this:

```
proj_root/
proj_root/doc              # Sphinx root
proj_root/doc/build
proj_root/doc/links        # Remember to version this
proj_root/doc/links/my_command.py -> ../../bin/my_command
proj_root/doc/source
proj_root/doc/source/conf.py
proj_root/bin
proj_root/bin/my_command   # Actual code
```

The advantage I see for this method is that you do not polute your `bin` directory with `.py` files that are just duplicates of the actual scripts.

One could probably also [try to hack this through the `imp` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601083/8280541) to get it, but I think that would be uglier.  I haven't tried that.