# How do I import python scripts that have a custom extension instead of default .py?

Tags: python, dsl, glob, python-import

I have a 'test engine' (which is a big python script that defines a lot of functions) that can run multiple 'test suites' (which are also just python scripts, that uses the functions from the test-engine to define some custom tests).

It is intended that the test-cases should be written by non-programmers so for pedagogic reasons I want to enforce that they give their scripts a `.tcs` extension instead of a `.py` extension.

When they doubleclick the main-application, the test engine will find all the `.tcs` files in the same directory using `glob()` and `import` all of them to execute their statements sequentially.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that discussion. `imp.load_source("testscript","testscript.tcs")` solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alex Thornton for [pointing out the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension).

`imp.load_source("importname","script.extension")`