# How to import a Python module into a local variable using an arbitrary path?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a python file as a config file.  In my real program, I let the user specify the config file at the command line.

Here's my example:

`some_randomly_named_file.py`:

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta

PROJECT = "my project"
ENABLED_FORMATS = ['xml', 'json', 'yaml']
EXPIRATION=3600

#DEBUG = True
#TESTING = False

LOG_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'logs')
```

The file is stored here: `/foo/bar/baz/some_randomly_named_file.py`

...and then in `myapp.py`:

```
# parse the command line and get the path
path_to_file = '/foo/bar/baz/some_randomly_named_file.py'

# load the python file at path_to_file into local variable myconfig
# [What do I write here to accomplish this?]

# And now we have a local variable called myconfig
print(myconfig.PROJECT)
```

Output:

```
my project
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @sandeep mentioned. Just add your source file (config.py) to your `sys` path. When you add this config.py file to your path, Python treats the file (and its contents) like an ordinary module. Here's a bit more of an explanation:

```
# Load your config.py as a module
import sys
sys.path.append("/foo/bar/baz/") # Path to config.py parent folder

import config # Import as a regular module

print(config.PROJECT)
"my project"
```

You can use [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255737/importing-variables-from-another-file-python) for reference.

Comment: The file name and path are randomly named.  I won't know the path, nor the name of the file at compile time.  I couldn't say "import config" in the code because I don't know the name.  I updated the question to reflect that the file is user-defined / randomly named.

Comment: Well your question was poorly asked @010110110101. Please make sure to include all of this relevant information in the question, and update the question as needed so that we don't submit virtually irrelevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your path to sys.path

Ex: if your config file is myconfig.py and present under /foo/bar/baz.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/foo/bar/baz/")
import myconfig
local_var = myconfig.PROJECT
```

You can use **os.path.basename()** and **os.path.dirname()** to retrieve the values entered by user.

### Sample program to get config filename and directory path from User

test.py

```
import sys
import os

file_path = sys.argv[1]
dir_name = os.path.dirname(file_path)
file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

sys.path.append(dir_name)
print dir_name
print file_name
```

## Output

```
#python test.py /var/log/syslog
/var/log
syslog
```

Comment: That won't work for this.  How would the variable "myconfig" (in my example) become populated like that?

Comment: Do you want to import all the contents of a module into a variable? I do not think that is possible.

Comment: sys.path.append("/foo/bar/baz/")
import myconfig
#assign to local variable
my_local_var = myconfig.PROJECT

Comment: my understanding of your question is that you want to access the content of your module via arbitrary path. Please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: The file name and path are randomly named.  I won't know the path, nor the name of the file at compile time.  I couldn't say "myconfig" in the code.  I updated the question to reflect that the file is user-defined / randomly named

Comment: I have added example. using that you can handle random filename and directory path.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution based on an answer from @Redlegjed in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path).

Here it is modified a bit:

```
import os
import importlib.machinery

path_to_file = '/foo/bar/baz/some_randomly_named_file.py'

module_dir, module_file = os.path.split(path_to_file)
module_name, module_ext = os.path.splitext(module_file)

x = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader(module_name, path_to_file).load_module()

print(myconfig.PROJECT)
```

A list of related and helpful articles:

[How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

[Python 3.4: How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381264/python-3-4-how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

[Import arbitrary python source file. (Python 3.3+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3)