# Python import file

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a file from a different directory, I've tried some of suggestions but none seemed to work for me.

In particular sys.path.insert(...) would not work for me, because I will not have constant absolute path to the file.

I have the following structure where my python files live:

```
project/packages/package_type/package/package_name/root/usr/bin/
```

So I need to import

```
project/packages/package_type/foo/root/usr/bin/foo 
(file does not have .py extension, but is a python file)
```

from

```
project/packages/package_type/bar/root/usr/share/bar/modules/foobar/bar.py
```

The folder with the file I need to import has an empty `__init__.py` file
I also tried

```
import package-type.foo.root.usr.bin.foo as foo
```

I am not sure how it's intended to use, since it is intended for Arch Linux package, and the files will simply be exported to /usr/bin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension (about importing a python file without .py extension)

Comment: By the way, I did not understand what you really want to do : where are you executing your program ?

Comment: @FunkySayu It will be arch linux package. So there is a path to it, but I don't want to hardcode it in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to simply provide environment capabilities similar to installed target Arch Linux / whatever package. That is, your Python packages should be reachable through `PYTHONPATH`. This is more conceptual than technical problem.

As FunkySayu asked in the comment -- where are you executing your program -- this is a crucial question. What is important, your module should be **tested** somewhere: `import`'ed and then used. That way you can do with `sys.path` whatever you want in your test `main.py` -- in particular `sys.path.append()`. You should be then able to import any package in a way that will work for installed target package environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [`pkg_utils`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html) or [`setuptools.find_packages()`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages).