# Getting import error saying there is no module

Tags: python, import

I want to import a color module but I am getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'scripts.UltraColor'
```

Import code:

```
from scripts.UltraColor import *
```

[image]

The import code is in `pygameTest.py`

Comment: Maybe try `import UltraColor` or `from UltraColor import *` (or the name of the module within that you might want). This would need your `scripts` folder to be an import location. Alternatively, move `UltraColor.py` to your `venv` folder and try again.

Comment: What Python version, and what platform? And can you `import sys, os; print(sys.path); print(sys.argv[0]); print(os.getcwd())` at the top of your program?

Comment: Please add to your question the sys.path before calling to import scripts.UltraColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here, as far as I can see on that screenshot is UltraColor file doesn't have the .py extension, for import to work properly you'll need to rename it from `UltraColor` to `UltraColor.py`, otherwise will raise an `ImportError` exception.

For more information, take a look to this one. [Import a python module without the .py extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension)