# The imp module is deprecated

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

Whenever I try to use "sklearn" in PyCharm, I get the following error on the console.

> DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
> import imp

I am not sure if it should bother me, because program still working, but it's annoying. How can I get rid of it?

I made every change, people recommended in linked question but the error is still there.

Comment: See this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html and this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib

Comment: This is not an error but a warning.  You even write yourself "DeprecationWarning".  Any warning can be ignored.

Comment: @MERose but it outputs a message and shows to the user and messes up the screen making it difficult to ignore

Comment: And when one see a huge warning sign e.g. red sign ahead, it is not always clever to ignore

Comment: Is there any way to make this disappear? I tried to suppress the warning through the python3 warning module but no luck.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate. It is also NOT a Python or sklearn issue, but purely a PyCharm issue. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000058690-Module-not-found-in-PyCharm-but-externally-in-Python which is a thread started before this question was posted and was added to as recently as April of 2020. There were many suggestions made but no clear solution presented.

Answer (score -10):

I deleted the code that imports "imp", from "cloudpickle.py" and the warning is gone but I hope I didn't mess up anything. You can also simply ignore this, since it's not an error.

Edit: I don't want to remove the question or answer because people still visit this page but this is not a solution and it is a bad way to handle it, just ignore this warning. I did this in my very amateur days, sorry :(

Comment: I'd rather change it to `import importlib` than delete it

Comment: Why did you delete?

Comment: Because I was trying to make the error gone.But I don't think it's the right way.

Comment: delete could break other thing, because the interpret might get to: line 936 mod = imp.new_module(name). Fix the module or ignore the error ...