# Import text file as a module in Python

Tags: python, text, import

I want to import a plain text file, no matter the extension cause I want to use my own, as a module in python.

For example. I have the strings for my program in separated .py files, and, depending on what language is selected, I import one file or the other.

Everything works well with this, but, I want to make this file, apparently not readable for a common user, so, I want to give them a custom extension that any of the programs installed can't read.
But, due that `import` only work with .py files, I want to know if there is a way to do this with other file types.
Or if is it another way to do something like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe read file sources and use eval method?

You may use it as

```
def import_module(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        file_contents = file.read()
    module_object =  exec(file_contents)
    return module_object
```

But that variant are not secure!

And such question was in stackoverflow [read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension)

Comment: Ok, this works as expected, but, why this isn't secure?

Comment: Because, maybe that file will be replaced with file with some code for getting remote access to computer wich execute your program

Comment: as another variant (such insecure), you may compile your code into some variable in code, and write it as pickled file in working directory

Comment: @DavidGonzálezBlazman, make my answer as right if it helps your

Comment: Ok, I have this file encoded and with control words to make sure this is the correct file so I can use exec properly secured.
Thanks!

Comment: Note: This answer doesn't work, in-so-far as it's not equivalent to `import` or `importlib.import_module` since it doesn't import any of the imports present within the module... :/