# Use custom python toolbox in arcpy script

Tags: python, arcpy

Is it possible to use a custom python toolbox (pyt) in a scripting environment (arcpy). For example I have created a .pyt toolbox and want to be able to call the individual tools in a scripting environment. Can one import the toolbox something like import example.pyt and then call the tools?

thanks for any information.

Comment: The way you do this is to create a normal python module that happens to have a .pyt file that relies on the functions and class in the module. Here's an example: https://github.com/Geosyntec/python-propagator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS, there is a function available [`arcpy.ImportToolbox(PathToToolbox)`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/importtoolbox.htm). This will allow importation of tools into an arcpy script.

Comment: Cool, I learned something new. You should mark your solution as accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to load a module with other file extensions, however, if it is your own custom made toolbox, you should rather refactor your toolbox and keep the toolbox's functionality in a separate module which is then used by your toolbox and your external script. Paul H's comment points to a good example.

However, if you are not able to refactor the toolbox, then you could use the package [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). Here is an example based on another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602645/42659):

For this example, consider that your `toolbox.pyt` has a function `say_hello()`.

```py
from importlib.util import spec_from_loader, module_from_spec
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader 

spec = spec_from_loader("toolbox", SourceFileLoader("toolbox", r"/path/toolbox.pyt"))
toolbox = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(toolbox)

toolbox.say_hello()
```

In addition, adding `sys.modules['toolbox'] = toolbox` allows you to import `toolbox` in other Python files after above code run.

**Note:** IMHO, if you have a chance to refactor the toolbox, a refactoring should be preferred.