# PyQt4 - "See the log file for details" error

Tags: python, pyqt4, xmpppy

I have made an application using Python and recently i found that i can use py2exe to make executables for windows.

The problem is that a library i am using (xmpppy) produces this error

> DeprecationWarning: the md5 module is deprecated; use hashlib instead

and when i try to run the executable a dialog appears saying this

> See the logfile 'C:\Python26\P2E\MyApp\dist\MyApp.exe.log' for details

any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Those error messages seem instructive enough...

Comment: Try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python when you build the executable

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the following lines down `import sys`

```
sys.stdout = open(“my_stdout.log”, “w”)
sys.stderr = open(“my_stderr.log”, “w”)
```

For more information you can read [this](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/StderrLog)

Answer (score -2):

when a python script .py has any error it shows in console but when you run python .exe file it genrates .exe.log file when error accured.so go to your folder and see that there is a .exe.log file is there showing errors.