# spyder: python: theano: How to disable warnings in spyder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, theano

I running machine learning algo's with theano.  I have been getting lot of warnings of DeprecationWarning.  coming from numpy package. I want to disable this warnings pls suggest option. 
warning nature:fromnumeric.py:932: DeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future

I tried following  run configure added command line option  -W ignore  or -W ignore::DeprecationWarning but none of this is working

alternatively fixing the warning solution is fine for me. looks like its fixed in theano https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/Hf7soRrnh8w but I dont know where to find this updated version of theano

I am using Anaconda distribution 2.0.1 windows 8.1 - 64 bit

thanks

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/879249/438386) here in StackOverflow. In that post there are other suggestions you can follow in case that one doesn't work.

Comment: thanks Carlos Cordoba,  none of those options worked however I found something that worked,        
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        main()

Comment: I'm really glad you've been able to figure it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link to update Theano to the development version. I should be fixed:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

In resume, run one of those 2 command:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

or (if you want to install it for the current user only):

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git --user
```