# captureWarnings set to True doesn't capture warnings

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I would like to log all warnings. I thought that setting `captureWarnings` to `True` should do the trick, but it doesn't. Code:

```
import logging
import warnings

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(u'./test.log')
logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.captureWarnings(True)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.info(u'Test')
warnings.warn(u'Warning test')
```

My expectation is that 'Warning test' should appear in test.log, but it doesn't; only 'Test' is put in the log file.

How to capture all warnings and redirect them to the log file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [`logging.captureWarnings`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) documentation:

> Warnings issued by the warnings module will be redirected to the
>   logging system. Specifically, a warning will be formatted using
>   `warnings.formatwarning()` and the resulting string **logged to a logger
>   named 'py.warnings' with a severity of WARNING**.

You probably want something like this:

```
import logging
import warnings

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(u'test.log')
logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.captureWarnings(True)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
warnings_logger = logging.getLogger("py.warnings")

logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
warnings_logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)

logger.info(u'Test')
warnings.warn(u'Warning test')
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

In an *application* codebase, instead of explicitly configuring the `py.warnings` logger as other answers here suggest, you instead can - and probably want to - configure the *root* logger. This will:

- Log stuff from `py.warnings` (the logger that the `captureWarnings` integration logs with)
- Log stuff from libraries that create their own logger and log to it
- Allow you to directly log using the logging module functions like `logging.info` instead of making a logger object

The following simple demo logs your warning as you want it to:

```
import logging
import warnings

from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

logger_file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(u'./test.log')
logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.captureWarnings(True)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()

root_logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logging.info(u'Test')
warnings.warn(u'Warning test')
```

Answer (score 4):

`logging.captureWarnings` is not using your logger. It uses a logger named `'py.warnings'`. You will need to configure that logger to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

*Not directly relevant for the OP, but may be useful for others winding up here based on the title:*

Another reason for warnings not to show up in your logs would be if you use [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) with `record=True`.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
import logging
import warnings

logging.basicConfig()  # configures the root logger

logging.captureWarnings(True)

warnings.warn('logged')

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.warn('also logged')


with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as warnings_caught:
    warnings.warn('not logged')

# show warnings recorded
print([w.message for w in warnings_caught])
```