# How to get rid of warning "DeprecationWarning generator 'ngrams' raised StopIteration"

Tags: python, ipython, nltk, kaggle

While working on a Kaggle notebook I ran into an issue. The following code block:

```
from nltk import ngrams
def grams(tokens):
    return list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
negative_grams = preprocessed_negative_tweets.apply(grams)
```

resulted in a red box appearing saying

```
/opt/conda/bin/ipython:5: DeprecationWarning: generator 'ngrams' raised StopIteration
```

The variable `preprocessed_negative_tweets` is a Pandas data frame containing tokens.

Anyone know how to make this go away?

(Full notebook available [here](https://www.kaggle.com/langkilde/d/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment/sentiment-classification-on-tweets-about-airlines))

Comment: The cause of the warning is the change in behavior described in [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/). How to best make it go away I can't say exactly, but you may need to just filter and [ignore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/879173/699305) the `DeprecationWarning`...

Comment: Quick question. Which nltk version are you using? Also which Python version are you using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To anyone else who doesn't want or can't suppress the warning.

This is happening because `ngrams` is raising `StopIteration` exception to end a generator, and this is deprecated from Python 3.5.

You could get rid of the warning by changing the code where the generator stops, so instead of raising `StopIteration` you just use Python's keyword `return`.

More on: [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)

Comment: I have a generator: `while True: yield itertools.chain(...)`. How would you convert that?

Comment: @OrangeDog You can use this: `yield from itertools.chain(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a wrapper like this one:

```
def get_data(gen):
    try:
        for elem in gen:
            yield elem
    except (RuntimeError, StopIteration):
        return
```

and then (according to your example):

```
data = get_data(ngrams(tokens, 3))
```

should do the trick

Comment: or just `yield from gen`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to quiet all warnings, you can do:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

We should listen to these warnings...

Comment: Nobody do this, you stand to miss all sorts of important and relevant warnings. They wouldn't exist unless the core developers made some sort of mistake. Just fix your code.

Comment: Sometimes warnings are triggered by third party libraries and one can't simply change that source code. I agree one should be cautious when filtering warnings--as always in programming, with great power comes great responsibility. You should only filter warnings if you know what you're doing...