# Remove deprecated warnings from python

Tags: python, ssim

I am new to python and currently working on an image processing project in which I need to compare two images. For image comparison, I am using structural similarity function which is already there in python.
But, each and every time I use that function, it gives me proper results but also dumps a warning multiple times like this:

```
C:\Users\abc\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure\_structural_similarity.py:224: skimage_deprecation: Call to deprecated function ``structural_similarity``. Use ``compare_ssim`` instead.
  def structural_similarity(X, Y, win_size=None, gradient=False,
```

I thought the warning wants me to use compare_ssim function instead of structural_similarity function. So, I changed to this: `from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim` But same warnings are coming. I am using this function for multiple images in a single execution so I need to scroll a lot to find exactly where my results are amidst the warnings.

**I need to disable these deprecated warnings to keep my console clean.** Any solution for this? I tried to search but everything was too complicated for me. Please help.

**ALSO** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python) might be a possible duplicate to this question but I can not understand how to implement the accepted answer on Spyder using an IPython console in windows.

Comment: When you use `compare_ssim` the warning should not occur, are you sure you changed it everywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore deprecation warnings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python)

Comment: @moritzg Yes the function I am calling is in loop so I needed to change it only once!