# Deprecation Warning : Please use nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer instead.'

Tags: python, nltk

Could you please let me know how to disable the below warning.

run.py:417: DeprecationWarning:

The StanfordTokenizer will be deprecated in version 3.2.5.
Please use nltk.parse.corenlp.CoreNLPTokenizer instead.'
  self.tokenizer = StanfordTokenizer(jar_path)

note: I already tried this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python) but still not working.

Comment: It's usually best to listen to deprecation warnings as the newer ways are usually more reliable and secure.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49345866/610569