# Ignore DeprecationWarning for Python executables (console scripts) while importing

Tags: python

scikit-learn gives a lot of warnings when it is being imported.
It appears I cannot wrap the imports with a suppress as in:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
import sklearn #Throws warning!
```

It's mentioned that:

```
python -W ignore::DeprecationWarning some_script.py
```

can work, but I'm interested in the case where you would run it as a console script (from being installed with setup.py):

```
myapp
```

How to suppress the warnings that users should not care about (only the library creators)?

**Any of the suggested answers in [How to ignore deprecation warnings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python) do not help**

I even tried to add `-W ignore::DeprecationWarning` in the `/usr/bin/myapp` console script, but that does not help either.

Comment: @kabanus It's not a duplicate. They do NOT address my particular problem. As I mentioned, the warnings library does not help while importing `sklearn`, because it has to be filtered in the code of `sklearn`. So I'd appreciate it if you'd remove your downvote. It's also not possible to do `myapp -W ignore::DeprecationWarning`

Comment: I did not down vote. Can't you use the `warnings` library before the import?

Comment: @kabanus No, I already tried.

Comment: Hope my edit was OK. Let's delete these comments.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks for the moderation!

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce. What versions of Pyhon and `sklearn` are you using? I am not getting warnings.

Comment: @kabanus sklearn version 0.20.dev0 with Python 3.7.0