# sklearn: DeprecationWarning: theimp module is deprecated - safe to ignore?

Tags: scikit-learn, deprecation-warning, python-importlib, imp

Whenever I try to use "sklearn", I get the following error:

> >>>from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
>
> /home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/argosv2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py:47: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
>     import imp

I am not sure if it should bother me, because program still working (of course we can [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python) warning deprecation in Python) - but is this safe ?

Also, this following is not giving any warning for some reason

> import imp

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally it should be safe to ignore deprecation in package that you don't maintain yourself. In the future, either the guy who maintain the package will fix it , and if there is no such one - you could either stop using this package or be that guy...