# can't stop Deprecation Warning from showing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read values from an Excel file and when I do:

```
for i in range(1, row_num + 1): 
        try:
            cell_obj = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1)
```

I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_squared_range (Use ws.iter_rows()).
  for row in self.get_squared_range(column, row, column, row):
```

I've tried to implement what the Python documentation says, but it just didn't work or I wasn't using it properly, I also tried to do the following:

```
for i in range(1, row_num + 1): 
        try:
            cell_obj = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1) 
            myList.append((cell_obj).value)   
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

but again, nothing is happening. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: As per the discussions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python), you need to call that _before_ whatever code that is generating the warnings. So put it right under the `import warnings` statement.

Comment: I did as you said and nothing has changed, the warning is still showing

Answer (score 3):

As the warning suggested, you may use the `iter_rows` method to iterate the cells.

Here is an example of using `iter_rows` to store cell values for first five rows.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'data.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
number_of_rows = sheet.max_row
number_of_columns = sheet.max_column

# Store values from first five rows
rows_iter = sheet.iter_rows(min_col=1, min_row=1,
                            max_col=number_of_columns, max_row=5)
values = [[cell.value for cell in row] for row in rows_iter]
print(values)
```

Output:

```
[['Segment', 'Country', 'Product', 'Discount Band', 'Units Sold', 'Manufacturing Price', 'Sale Price', 'Gross Sales', 'Discounts', ' Sales', 'COGS', 'Profit', 'Date', 'Month Number', 'Month Name', 'Year'], ['Government', 'Canada', 'Carretera', 'None', 1618.5, 3, 20, 32370, 0, 32370, 16185, 16185, datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1, 'January', '2014'], ['Government', 'Germany', 'Carretera', 'None', 1321, 3, 20, 26420, 0, 26420, 13210, 13210, datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), 1, 'January', '2014'], ['Midmarket', 'France', 'Carretera', 'None', 2178, 3, 15, 32670, 0, 32670, 21780, 10890, datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 6, 'June', '2014'], ['Midmarket', 'Germany', 'Carretera', 'None', 888, 3, 15, 13320, 0, 13320, 8880, 4440, datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1, 0, 0), 6, 'June', '2014']]
```

I have used [Sample Excel Spreadsheet provided by Microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962) as `data.xlsx`

Installed packages:

```
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
jdcal==1.4.1
openpyxl==2.6.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

Comment: yes, 'fixing' the code seems like a much better way to solve this than just trying to turn off the warning message

Comment: @EugeniaCastilla, 
I am glad it worked.
If the answer helped you, please upvote and accept it for future readers.  :)

Comment: how does the lib get to know the code is **iterate the cells**: `cell_obj = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Since Python is an iterative language, statements get executed one-by-one.

Try putting the below statement

`warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)`

before

`cell_obj = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 1)`

And it is advisable to have the warning filter statements at global space as locally suppressing a warning would not be reflective of the original intention.

Comment: hi varshith, I tried what you suggested, but still nothing has changed  :(

Comment: I generally suggest putting the filterwarnings at the top of the script just after any imports. It makes it easier to find later and it acts as a blanket over everything.