# How to suppress Depreciation warnings for pymodbus asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.9, deprecation-warning, pymodbus

We're using a third party library which still uses the old `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator and is generating a bunch of warnings on import.  I recognise this will break in future versions of python.  But for now we just want to turn off this warning so that it doesn't spam the user.

I've tried everything I can think of to silence this including every answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879173/how-to-ignore-deprecation-warnings-in-python) and even turning off all depreciation warnings:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

from pymodbus.client.asynchronous.async_io import (
    BaseModbusAsyncClientProtocol,
    ReconnectingAsyncioModbusTcpClient,
    ReconnectingAsyncioModbusTlsClient,
)
```

Nothing seems to silence it.